# what are delims used for tab completer

Tags: python, gnu, readline

I am reading some code about Readline Library I try to type  `readline.get_completer_delims()` it gives me delimiters like ~!@#$%^&*()-=+[{]}\|;:'",<>/?
My question is what the meaning of those delimiters for tab complete? can someone explain ?

```
readline.get_completer_delims()
```

Answer (score 1):

Per [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/readline.html#readline.get_completer_delims):

> Set or get the word delimiters for completion. These determine the start of the word to be considered for completion (the completion scope). These functions access the rl_completer_word_break_characters variable in the underlying library.

These are characters after which the tab completer should consider the start of a "word", and ignore characters on the line prior to that one. For example, if you wanted to implement a tab completer for attributes and methods on Python objects you might add `.` to this list, so when hitting tab after a `.` it would indicate that you want completion for whatever comes after the dot.